# SQL Server stored procedure woes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can some one please help me with dynamic search stored procedure?

This is my stored procedure:

```
 DECLARE mycursorForCountry CURSOR FOR
    SELECT CountryNames 
    FROM [Countries].[dbo].[World] 
    WHERE UserID = @userID

    OPEN mycursorForCountry

    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursorForCountry INTO @CountryNames

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @CountryTbl
           SELECT DISTCINT * 
           FROM ufn_Split((@CountryNames),',')

        FETCH NEXT FROM mycursorForCountry INTO @CountryNames
    END

    CLOSE mycursorForCountry
    DEALLOCATE mycursorForCountry

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Information].[dbo].[Media] WHERE Country_Name IN('+@CountryNames+')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

I'm getting an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 260
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AFRICA'

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic sql statement here? While you could just pass the `@CountryNames` in query..

Comment: @Shaharyar this is one part of my code as i have other parts to query

Comment: Can you give us a sample on @CountryNames values?

Comment: Then you should post complete code

Comment: @Hadi South Africa so the code must return where country is South Africa

Comment: You appear to have accepted an answer that I suspect is entirely wrong. Did you not intend the query after the cursor to use the `@CountryTbl` table that the cursor was busy populating, rather than whatever happened to have been left over in your `@CountryNames` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
set @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Information].[dbo].[Media] WHERE  
  Country_Name IN('+@CountryNames+')'
```

hasn't wrapped the value returned by `@CountryNames` in single quotes. Change it to the following (using two single quotes escapes it into a single single quote):

```
set @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Information].[dbo].[Media] WHERE  
  Country_Name IN('''+@CountryNames+''')' 
  --              ^-------------------^------- added two single-quotes
```

**Suggestion**

When you are dynamically creating SQL statements in such a manner, print out the SQL statement using `print @SQL` for debugging purposes, to troubleshoot such cases. If you'd done so, you'd have noticed the contents of `@SQL` was the following incorrect query:

```
SELECT * FROM [Information].[dbo].[Media] WHERE Country_Name IN (AFRICA)
```

That would have indicated to you that you had a string in the `IN` statement that wasn't wrapped in quote marks.

---

**EDIT: To correctly generate a comma-separated list of countries**

```
DECLARE @CountryNames NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @CountryNames = (SELECT  '''' + CountryNames + ''',' 
FROM [Countries].[dbo].[World] 
WHERE UserID = @userID 
FOR XML PATH('') )

PRINT substring(@CountryNames, 1, len(@CountryNames) - 1)
```

The `FOR XML PATH('')` concatenates separate rows into a single row of comma-separated values, and the `substring()` function is used to remove the trailing comma.

This avoids the need of looping through a cursor to form the comma-separated list.

In this case, there is no need to insert two single quotes in the formation of the `@SQL` variable, as all required double-quotes are formed in the above statement itself.

---

**EDIT 2: Revised SQL**

The following is the complete SQL to do what you need. Note that it doesn't use cursors, nor does it use a table `@CountryTbl`:

```
DECLARE @CountryNames NVARCHAR(MAX) 

-- Prepares a comma-separated list of countries, e.g.: 'Africa','Nigeria', 
-- Note that there is a trailing comma 
SET @CountryNames = (SELECT  '''' + CountryNames + ''',' 
    FROM [Countries].[dbo].[World] 
    WHERE UserID = @userID 
    FOR XML PATH('') )

-- Remove the trailing comma 
SET @CountryNames = substring(@CountryNames, 1, len(@CountryNames) - 1) 

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Information].[dbo].[Media] WHERE Country_Name IN('+ @CountryNames +')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```